# Problema con slideshow en html

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, web

Estoy usando este codigo de slideshow https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Y el problema reside en que hasta que no le das a las bolitas las fotos no aparecen, el resto funciona bien. En el css hay un parametro dentro de .myslides que se llama display y esta puesto en "none", pero si lo cambio aparecen todas las fotos a la vey y practicamente destruye la web. A ver si se puede encontrar una solucion, gracias de antemano!

Mi codigo

```js
  var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
  background: url("./recursos/fondo.jpg");
  font-family: helvetica, arial, serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 70px #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 70px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 70px #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.decor {
  background: #6EAF8D;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #CDEBDB 50%, #6EAF8D 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #CDEBDB 50%, #6EAF8D 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #CDEBDB 50%, #6EAF8D 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(left, white 50%, #6EAF8D 50%);
  background-size: 50px 25%;;
  padding: 2px;
  display: block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

ul:before,
ul:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  background: #2B2B2B;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #2B2B2B 7%, #333333 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #2B2B2B 7%, #333333 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #2B2B2B 7%, #333333 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #2B2B2B 7%, #333333 100%);
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #0E0E0E;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

ul.primary li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-right: 1px solid #3D3D3D;
}

ul.primary li:last-child a {
  border-right: none;
}

ul.primary li a:hover {

  color: #000;
}

ul.sub {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #BEBEBE;
  width: 35%;
  display:none;
}

ul.sub li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.sub li a {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  color: #000;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

ul.sub li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.sub li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

ul.primary li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
}

ul.primary li:hover a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  text-shadow: none;
}

ul.primary li:hover > a{
  color: #000;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .decor {
    padding: 3px;
  }

  .wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }

   li {
    float: none;
  }

  ul.primary li:hover a {
    background: none;
    color: #8B8B8B;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
  }

  ul.primary li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    background: #272727;
    color: #fff;
  }

  ul.sub {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  ul.sub li a {
    background: #272727;
    border: none;
    color: #8B8B8B;
  }

  ul.sub li a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background: none;
  }
}

.cuadrado {
  width: 900px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: #2c3e50 2px solid;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

.titulo {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  align: center;
}

.minus {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.textodebajo {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: #2c3e50 opacity: 0.50;
  max-width: 750px;
  align: justify;
}

/*slider*/
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 750px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<div class="wrap">
<span class="decor"></span>
<nav>
  <ul class="primary">
    <li>
      <a href="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Week</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="">Week 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Week 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Week 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Week 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Cities</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="">Leipzig</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Berlin</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Dresden</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Free time</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="">Vitalis</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Leipzig</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Berlin</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
<br><br>
<center>
  <div class=cuadrado id=centro>
    <br><br>
    <h1 class=titulo>My travel to germany</h1>
    <br>

    <!-- Slideshow container -->
    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="./recursos/picworking.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="imagen-1">
        <div class="text">Working on the office</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="./recursos/picxavito.jpg" style="width:90%"  alt="imagen-2">
        <div class="text">With my friend</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="./recursos/picdreden.jpg" style="width:95%"  alt="imagen-3">
        <div class="text">Good panoramic of the city</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
    <br><br>
<div>
  <p class="textodebajo">Hi my name is Daniel and im gona tell you on this website my travel to germany, how i meet amazing people
  , discovered new sites, new cultures, a lot of good food, and the most important: the things i learned</p>
</div>


  </div>
  <div id=footer>
    <br>
    <p class=minus>By Daniel Valentin Alonso Maqueira</p>
  </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias a los comentarios con los consejos

Comment: Buenas, primero de todo puedes pasar tu codigo?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Una observación: el ejemplo del enlace utiliza javascript no java. A lo mejor tendrías que editar tu pregunta y cambiar la etiqueta java por la de javascript. Y si la estas editando por favor agrega el código. En el ejemplo del enlace no vero "bolitas", y funciona correctamente.

Comment: @KeTeMeTo hecho

Comment: @enxaneta gracias por la observacion, ya he puesto el codigo.

Comment: @DanielAlonsoMaqueira Si aceptas mi edición he metido el código en un snippet para que pueda ser ejecutado desde aquí y facilitar a los demás que te puedan responder. Dicho esto, no veo ningún problema con el funcionamiento del slide, ¿Puedes detallar un poco mas el problema de como funciona y como debería de funcionar?

Comment: A mi no me funciona tampoco estoy intentando averiguar porque y pasa exactamente lo que comentas que solo carga el slide cuando se hace click en las burbujas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías mostrar siempre la primera foto por defecto, del primer elemento que tenga la clase ".mySlides". Sería asi:

```
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

.mySlides:first-of-type {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Ya esta solucionado.

Comment: @DanielAlonsoMaqueira Si esta respuesta te ha servido para solucionar el problema, marcala como "aceptada" para que le pueda ayudar a mas gente. Y si no es así pero ya has encontrado el problema por tu cuenta, lo puedes poner como respuesta a tu propia pregunta!

Comment: Perdona el descuido, ya está marcado!